# Is it better to have a large chunk of text, or individual p tags for SEO

Tags: seo, technical-seo

We have a website, where a lot of text is required for SEO to be preloaded on to the website.

Currently, it has been loaded with each text/sentence loaded into it's own `<p> [...] </p>` tag, with thousands of `<p>` tags being generated.

However, SEO wise, could this SEO required text be simply dumped into one large `<p>` tag. As large number of DOM elements hurts website loading speeds, is the other reason we want to have one single `<p>` tag with all the necessary text.

- Could this work?
- Would it hurt SEO?
- Would there be difference in DOM size and complexity ? And whether it'll be beneficial having one large chunk of text?

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself, would anyone want to read that? Creating content purely for SEO and not the user is misguided and will hurt you in the long run.

Using one `<p>` tag is the wrong approach. Concentrate on creating quality content and using [semantic HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantics_in_html).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the invisible elephant in the room, (which is the most important part), what is best for the presentation to the visitor; And, the visitor interaction with the page is a rating factor. Does the visitor click the back button and go to the next site because the content is hard to read? Or linger on your site and on return to google search for something entirely different? If the visitor searches for the same keywords in the future does he click your site as his first pick? In other words, does the AI believe he likes your content?

### Are these pages SEO/SEM

The way your question reads, it is hard to imagine that these pages are actually bringing in traffic (SEO). or that these pages are resulting in increased sales (SEM). It sounds like the pages are just a long list of words? If they don't have human views, then changing them or even removing them will not harm SEO. Nobody I know is scrolling through thousands of paragraphs.

Maybe if they are top 10,000 baby names. I would keep that content on separate lines for readability. Or break them up alphabetically to different pages. But I'd not consider those as SEO rather just content for people about to have a child.

Same for website names, I'd never read a page from left to right of website names. One per line please and give me a search feature.

A group of 1000 phone numbers would be fine if they are not on their own line. Assuming they are in order. But at least break them up into groups of pages.

### Origins of reduce volume of tags

Reducing the volume of tags and attributes of tags has been speculated as helpful by those who write for a keyword density of a specific percent. The density can be calculated as (page size)/5 = words or an actual word count taken.

There is no evidence that I've ever seen (apart from time taken to render) that

```
<!doctype HTML>
<p>These keyword1 keyword2 keyword3</p>
```

page does better than

```
    <!doctype HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<style>
/* long style sheet */
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This keyword1 more words about product.</p>
    <p>keyword2, more words related to this feature of the product.</p>
    <p>keyword3 more words related to the value of the product.</p>  
<script id="1">
// this is 1000 words of script.
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Removing <p> is not going to improve render time -- although removing needless CSS rules and scripts that provide no value might.

These keyword-density algos are also virtually replaced by natural language algos that prefer proper paragraphs.

### Having a P for each keyword does not help SEO either.

If the keywords are say a list of ingredients for a recipe, it does not help SEO by putting them into different paragraphs. This reads perfectly as well.

```
<p>
This keyword1 more words about the product. 
keyword2, more words related to this feature of the product. 
keyword3 more words related to the value of the product.
</p>
```

No better no worse for the bot. The question is which reads better for the invisible elephant in the room?

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right Pete. Creating content purely for SEO and not the user is misguided and will hurt you in the long run. Users can easily spot content that is written purely for SEO, and they will be less likely to engage with it.

Using one `<p>` tag is also the wrong approach. This will make your content difficult to read and scan, and it will not be as beneficial for SEO as well structured content with individual p tags.

As for the number of [DOM elements](https://www.commercegurus.com/dom-size/), having a large number of p tags will not have a significant impact on your website's loading speed. However, if you have a very large number of DOM elements, it could potentially slow down your website slightly.

Answer (score 0):

There are different situations, in fact. It often happens that there is no difference. No matter how I tried it, it did not help in most niches. Google didn't care, the end result was good content.
But in very competitive niches, I did "p" for 1 paragraph. So that all aliases and lsi are in the heap, in group 1 "p". And it helped_)